# bbpress - logged users can't see forums, logged out ones can

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have a forum set up. If you're not logged in the forums show fine, if you log in then it can't find any forums.

```
Oh bother! No forums were found here!
```

I've tried it in all skins, I've tried disabling all plugins. I've cleared cookies. Same result.

Using skin twentyfifteen purely for testing but it happens in every one I've tried. No joy from bbpress' own help system

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to user role in the forum for your user, check the forum role on the user edit panel on the admin side.